# HTML refresh page from iframe

Tags: html, ajax, iframe

I've a simple web page that is divided into three iframe A,B,C.

The iframe B executes an Ajax request and it should refresh the page to redirect to my login page.
Obviously, the login page happears only within iframe B. There is a way to redirect entirely page?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a simple check of top.location work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        if (top.location!= self.location) {
            top.location = self.location.href
        }
    //-->
</script>
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty good. But if I have this configuration: top<iframeA<iframeB, i.e. top contains FrameA that contains FrameB, how can I navigate with top javascript objects?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<script>
    Window.top.location = 'new url';
</script>
```